# Validating a Field on Tab Out Using ASP.NET Entity Framework

Tags: jquery, asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to get a field to validate on tab out rather than on submit. Is there some way to make this work? I assume it would be a JQuery script for the on change event but I am not sure what method would be used.

Here is my on change script currently, this just runs a method called GetUserDetails which is unrelated to this issue and populates my fields automatically. I need it to run or trigger validation as well though. It needs to know if the username exists but it doesn't seem to work in this case when I try the `alert` method.

```
<script>
    $('#username').on("change", function (event) {
        var userName = $('#username').val();
        //make an ajax request
        var model = JSON.parse('{"userId":"' + userName + '"}');

        //precess the retrieved json

        //place json fields on the input boxes in html

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "/Employees/GetUserDetails/",
            data: model,
        }).done(function (data) {
            if (data.FullName == null || data.FullName == "") {
                $('#username').alert("Username does not exist.");
            }
            $('#fullname').val(data.FullName);
            $('#email').val(data.email);
            $('#phone').val(data.phone);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want it to do what it would do if I hit submit instead, for a given field. My model has the annotations for validation.

Comment: tab out means if you leave event of the element?

Comment: Tabbing out of the field triggers the change event yes.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: 
You can't validate it until you submit the form. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs

but what we can do is a custom validation on client-side.

===========================

You could use `.blur()` to detect lost focus.

> The blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus.
>   https://api.jquery.com/blur/

```js
$(function(){
  $('#txt').on("blur", function (event) {
    if ($(this).val() == ""){
      alert("please input value");
   }
   else{
    var userName = $('#username').val();
      //make an ajax request
      var model = JSON.parse('{"userId":"' + userName + '"}');

      //precess the retrieved json

      //place json fields on the input boxes in html

      $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url: "/Employees/GetUserDetails/",
          data: model,
      }).done(function (data) {
          $('#fullname').val(data.FullName);
          $('#email').val(data.email);
          $('#phone').val(data.phone);
      });
   } 
  })

  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="text" name="sample" id="txt"/>
  <input type="text" name="sample2" id="txt1"/>
```

Comment: No, on change works, what I want it to do is to trigger the built in model validation schema. I want it to do what it would do if I hit submit instead, for that field. My model has the annotations for validation. Maybe I should add those to the question.

Comment: you can't have that without submitting the form

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs